# Why can't DISPLAY be set to a hostname?

Tags: ssh, x11

On CentOS 6.7 when I `ssh` from a local workstation into a remote host and set the DISPLAY env variable to the workstation using either the hostname or the IP address I can not open any X displays.

Example:

```
$ ssh -Y host1
$ export DISPLAY=ws1:0.0    # workstation hostname=ws1
$ xeyes
Can't not open display
```

However, the following works.

```
$ ssh -Y host1
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
$ xeyes           # works as expected
```

What is preventing the X-display from working when I set $DISPLAY using a hostname?

Answer (score 3):

Remote access to X servers is generally forbidden nowadays due to serious security issues.

Either firewalls and/or X server settings prevent these connections to succeed.

Only Local and Unix domain sockets are then allowed to connect, thus only **localhost:*server[.display]*** or no host at all **:*server[.display]*** are usable settings.

To figure out if your X server is listening to a TCP port, you can run this command and see if the X server (or ssh in case of tunneling) show up using ports in the 6000+ range:

```
$ sudo netstat -anp|grep -w LISTEN
```

If your server only listen to unix bound sockets, that will show up using `lsof`:

```
$ sudo lsof -p $(pgrep Xorg)
```

These kind of lines represent unix sockets:

```
Xorg    1874 root   21u     unix 0xffff8800d5db4000      0t0      21169 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
```

To identify all processes listening on a TCP port, you can run this command:

```
$ sudo lsof -P | grep -w LISTEN
```

For example, here is the ssh daemon listening on TCP port 22:

```
sshd       1032              root    4u     IPv6              22727      0t0        TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: So what are the settings that enforce this? Or what are the firewall rules or ports that block this?

Comment: TCP ports are 6000+server number

Comment: `xhost +<hostname>` can be used to allow that specific host to connect.

Comment: how does one figure out the server number if you forget to use ssh -Y ?

Comment: xhost + and xhost +<hostname> does not work

Comment: `ssh -Y` is creating that server number. Don't confuse the tunnel ending port numbers.

Comment: What does tunnel ending port numbers mean?

Comment: `ssh -Y` is creating a tunnel between your local X server port, whatever it is (usually 6000) and an ad hoc port on the remote machine, 6010 if free, otherwise 6011 and so on. You have to retrieve 6000 from these TCP port numbers to get the display number to use.

Comment: How do you figure out what that 6000 + some offset port number? Is there an env variable, command, or temporary file?

Comment: The environment variable is `DISPLAY`. It is set either by your graphic environment startup program on the workstation side or by `ssh` if you tunnel X11 with `-X` or `-Y`.

Comment: That is useful information for troubleshooting. But the crux of the question is: what are the X settings or firewall settings that need to be changed to disable this behavior?

Comment: I answered to the question you asked: Why can't it be set?. About your last comment, you might want to ask a new question with more detailed information about your specific configuration. There are many different situations that can lead to X11 connectivity issues so there is no generic solution.

Comment: and disabling the security might not be the right approach to fix them…

Answer (score 1):

If the local X server is a reasonably modern version of the `Xorg` X server, it does not accept direct network connections by default. To enable this **old and fundamentally insecure** access method, you would need to modify the command line used to start your X server to include the `-listen tcp` option.

Older distributions would instead have the X server started with the `-nolisten tcp` option by default, and to enable the old-style unprotected network access you would need to remove that option from the X server command line.

I think most major Linux distributions started blocking unprotected X11 connections by default before the year 2000.